# How to disable CSRF for spring boot Actuator URLs for AWS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-security, csrf-protection

I have a Spring Boot application with CSRF enabled hosted on AWS. And I have followed this tutorial [enable CSRF for SpringBoot & AngularJS](http://sdqali.in/blog/2016/07/20/csrf-protection-with-spring-security-and-angular-js/)

I have disabled CSRF for

> "/healthcheck.js", "/health", "/info", "/actuator",
>                   "/beans", "/env", "/configprops", "/metrics", "/dump", "/autoconfig", "/mappings", "/trace"

actuator URLs along with the context path and the static files.

However, I still get 401 for /[contextpath]/healthcheck.js. Not sure if I am missing anything else.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @dur If I disable CSRF, then AWS treats the health check URL as normal URL and it asks for authentication. This happens only when I enable CSRF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to work after adding the url patterns to spring security permitAll.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(patterns).permitAll()...
```